# How to make both maps render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv

I have a model in blender that has two uv maps on it. The thing is only one will show up in viewport/render. It only allows me to render one, the other one wont show up anywhere. How do i make it so i can render and see both maps?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is [UV Map Node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/nodes/types/input/uv_map.html) which can be used to access to uv maps

Also [Attribute](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/nodes/types/input/attribute.html) node with Vector output and vu map name can be used

[image: uv map node result]

Comment: what did u use to connect the uv map node?

Comment: Image Texture, MixRGB then Shader

Comment: im preparing it for substance painter..i dont have any textures available yet

Comment: if you about displayed texture it's generated with UV Grid pattern type

Comment: alright i did what you did but still only one map will show up